# why I can't use a take() after a istream_view in c++20

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

The code shows my problem, I can't use `take(3)` after `istream_view`.

The error message is:

> /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/gcc/11.1.0_1/include/c++/11.1.0/ranges:1775:48: error: passing 'std::ranges::take_view<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::basic_istream_view<int, char, std::char_traits >, int (*)(int)> >::_CI' {aka 'const std::counted_iterator<std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::basic_istream_view<int, char, std::char_traits >, int (*)(int)>::_Iterator >'} as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
> 1775 |           { return __y.count() == 0 || __y.base() == __x._M_end; }

```cpp
#include <ranges>

using namespace std::views;
using namespace std::ranges;
int to_sq(int a){return a*a;}
int main()
{

    auto m_range = istream_view<int>(std::cin);
    // error
    for (auto i : m_range | transform(to_sq)|take(3))
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a gcc bug that has been [fixed in trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/6qx19fdvc). Also, as mentioned above, please include a definition of `to_sq`.

Answer (score 8):

This is [LWG 3391](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3391).

The `transform` here is irrelevant, just trying to iterate over `istream_view<int>(std::cin) | views::take(3)` is already a problem. From the issue:

> The code is invalid because `ranges::take_view::sentinel::operator==()` must call `counted_iterator::base()` to compare the underlying iterator against its sentinel, and therefore this `operator==()` requires that the underlying iterator is copy_constructible.

gcc 11.1 doesn't incorporate this fix yet (specifically [this commit](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/08f3287eefea1d7c244db795d018870e8148d1c8) which came out just a few weeks after 11.1 was released), but gcc trunk now does.